# Wordpress pagination links with query args

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-wordpress-pages

I have set some arguments to the `paginate_links` function and managed to do pagination with query args instead of path, but on the first page it does not rewrite my arguments, it just keeps the current page: if i'm on page 3 the first page url will be `?page=3` instead of empty. I need to clear it or set it as `?page=1`. I used the following code

```
global $wp_query;
$current = $wp_query->query_vars['page'] > 1 ? $wp_query->query_vars['page'] : 1;
echo paginate_links(
    [
        'base' => '%_%',
        'format' => '?page=%#%',
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'current' => $current,
        'show_all' => true,
        'type' => 'list',
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **'base' => '%_%'** Just change to below line. This will solve your problem.

```
'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
```

Comment: It doesn't work because i have the page in query args and it keeps my `?page=x` in the URL